# Symfony 6 routing on hosting doesnt work, on localhost it works, why?

Tags: symfony, routes, hosting

I have a problem, Im first time deploying a project online on webhosting but on hosting symfony routing doesnt work. The mainpage shows, everything else not.
Example:
127.0.0.1/login -> works
hosting.com/login -> doesn't work, 404 not found

in .htaccess i have this code for hiding /public/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/(\[^\\s?\]\*) \[NC\]
RewriteRule ^ %1 \[L,NE,R=301\]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).\*)$ public/$1 \[L,NC\]
```

I also tried to use /public/login - same results 404
I tried to put routes from controller into routes.yaml but aswell doesn't work
Well I don't really know how to solve it, I was thinking about adding something into .htaccess but I dont understand the logic of htaccess

Comment: https://symfony.com/components/Apache%20Pack and https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules-for-apache

Answer (score 0):

Please point your domain directly with `/public` path.
`www.domain.com --> var/www/public_html/project/public`

And your `.htaccess` file inside `/public` folder should below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```